# How can I Patch my Amazon EMR cluster with security updates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, amazon-systems-manager

I have an Amazon EMR cluster with 3 nodes (1 master and 2 core) running on Amazon EMR Release 5.31.0 AMI. I want to patch these nodes with security - critical and important patches as we would patch normal EC2 instances. Can we do this?

As EMR runs on EC2 instances in the background and the base OS of EMR Releases is Amazon Linux, I feel we can patch the nodes/instances either by SSH into the instances and running yum commands or using Patch Manager. Is it ok to do this way? Is it recommended?

But when I searched for the same, I found this article:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/create-custom-amis-and-push-updates-to-a-running-amazon-emr-cluster-using-amazon-ec2-systems-manager/

which is asking to use custom AMIs. I feel this is comparatively a long/tough process just to patch an EMR cluster. Is this the only correct way to do or do we have other ways?

Some are suggesting to clone the cluster and use the EMR release 6.x for the new cluster. ??

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: This isn't a common pattern because typically you would just destroy and create a new cluster. Using the standard workflow steps in EMR, a cluster automatically terminates after all steps run.

Comment: My cluster waits even after all the steps are completed and we don't terminate. The steps run every hour or so.